# JavaScript working on Firefox but not on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to create an `onclick` event with JavaScript when a user presses on a button it will check if a file has selected then it will fire the event and will change a CSS to an Element to `block` from `display: none`. However it is working perfectly with Firefox but it's not working with Google Chrome. I'm just using normal JavaScript. I'm curious why it's not working.

**Here is my code:**

**HTML**

```
<section id="spinnerLoader" class="mod model-1">
    <input type="file" name="userNames" id="files">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbtn" value="Submit">
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var inputID = document.getElementById('files').files;
  var clickbtn = document.getElementById('submitbtn');
  clickbtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if(inputID.length == 0){
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        var spinID = document.getElementById('spinnerLoader');
        spinID.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why exactly doesn't it work? is the length not updating like you expect it to? that would narrow the problem down quite a bit.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I checked console for errors but there are nothing on chrome console.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. The HTML could be helpful

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working.. It's perfectly working with Firefox

Comment: Do some debugging. Add some console.logs. Use the debugger. Anything more than just saying "Huh.. it doesn't work."

Comment: Like @j08691 has suggested, may you add the HTML?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What happens on click in Firefox that doesn't happen in Chrome?

Comment: Works just fine if you move `var inputID = document.getElementById('files').files;` to the inside of the click event.

Comment: let me check @PaulAbbott

Comment: @PaulAbbott Good catch. Can't get the number of files beforehand.

Comment: Yeah Thank You @PaulAbbott it worked but why is this happened any explanation for that ?

Comment: @Smalldeveloper That `var inputID` line grabs the number of files, so if you assign the value before the user selects any files, it will be `0`.  If you get the value after the user clicks the submit button, it will assign the correct number to the variable.

Comment: But why it was working with Firefox ?

Comment: That's a good question. Maybe Firefox returns the actual `files` object instead of a reference (so the length changes as the number of files changes).

Comment: @freginold Please Upvote if you think that the answer i created by the help of you guys is perfect.

Comment: @Smalldeveloper Looks good to me.

Comment: Ok Cool :) Thanks dude .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the help of [Paul Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123422/paul-abbott) by changing this code from:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputID = document.getElementById('files').files;
  var clickbtn = document.getElementById('submitbtn');
  clickbtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if(inputID.length == 0){
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        var spinID = document.getElementById('spinnerLoader');
        spinID.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

**To**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clickbtn = document.getElementById('submitbtn');
  clickbtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var inputID = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if(inputID.length == 0){
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        var spinID = document.getElementById('spinnerLoader');
        spinID.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

The code is working perfectly with Chrome Browser.

**Explanation by [freginold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5463636/freginold)**

That `var inputID` line grabs the number of files, so if you assign the value before the user selects any files, it will be `0`. If you get the value after the user clicks the submit button, it will assign the correct number to the variable.